# Kendo ui datepicker in inline editing grid

Tags: asp.net-mvc, kendo-ui

Since Our database is using AUS format date not US Format.

I have added this in my cshtml page, but it is not working since when it pass to the controller it still get the US Date format. Please advise

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/kendo/cultures/kendo.culture.en-AU.min.js")" ></script>
<script>
    kendo.culture("en-AU");
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is working correct. You don't need to use same format as in client side to server side. If it is converting correctly to the server side culture then you are ok. And  when  you are going to display the date in the ui kendo will format that value to correct culture again.

Comment: Thank you for your quick response. However, it does not save the value selected from kendo ui datepicker

Comment: Set the the culture to auto in the server side in web config,`<globalization  uiCulture="auto" culture="auto" />`

Comment: Or if you need to have a fixed culture you can set it `<globalization  uiCulture="en" culture="en-AU" />`

Comment: In the `<system.web>` section ?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/28714/discussion-between-jayantha-and-spidey)